# use HttpWebRequest to get redirected url instead of waiting for the entire page to load

Tags: .net, httpwebrequest

I have a page that redirects to a video (.3gp). The problem (from what i can tell) is that after begining the request from the original page, i get a very late response. I suppose this is because the web request waits for the data to download. Here is my code :

```
       System.Uri targetUri = new System.Uri(TextBlockTargetUri.Text);
       HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(targetUri);
        request.AllowReadStreamBuffering = true;
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(ReadWebRequestCallback), request);

 private void ReadWebRequestCallback(IAsyncResult callbackResult)
        {
            HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)callbackResult.AsyncState;
            HttpWebResponse myResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.EndGetResponse(callbackResult);


            using (StreamReader httpwebStreamReader = new StreamReader(myResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                string stuff2 = myResponse.ResponseUri.AbsoluteUri;
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => TextBlockResults.Text =  stuff2);
            }
            myResponse.Close();
        }
```

I only need the url, because the player i am using has a streaming method of its one, so i shouldn't wait for the entire video to download. How can i get only the redirect url and not wait for the video?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `HEAD` http method, just do:

```
 request.Method = "HEAD";
```

This method asks the server to return only the headers

Comment: worked like a charm! Thanks a lot! i'll approve the answer in 10 mins :)